# How to find perpendicular line of given 2 point?

Tags: flutter, math, canvas, geometry

I am trying to draw a perpendicular line on canvas in flutter , after some recap of my math , I failed to implement the formula into my code.

I have a point p1 and point p2 to draw a straight line,
[image: sample image]
but then I need draw a perpendicular line that pass through p3 (expected result is like blue line in the picture)

First of my code is find the line equation given two point (**p1**,**p2**). Below is how I find the **m** (slope).

```
double x1=p1.x;
double x2=p2.x;
double y1=p1.y;
double y2=p2.y;

double m=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
```

And to find the slope for the perpendicular line I am writing the code like below

```
//this code I expected to transform the previous m to negative reciprocal.
double invertedM = ( 1 / m ) * -1;
```

And then I have to find the new **c**(y-intercept) with my third point **p3** to form a new line equation. And substitute y1=0 and y2=screeen_height to draw the perpendicular line that pass through p3

```
double invertedC = p3.y / (invertedM * p3.x) ;

//get x give y = 0
qy1 = 0 ;
double findX1 = (qy1-invertedC)/invertedM;
Point answerPoint1 = Point(findX1,qy1);

//get x given y = screenheight
qy2 = screenheight ;
double findX2 = (qy2-invertedC)/invertedM;
Point answerPoint2 = Point(findX2,qy2);
```

**But somehow the result I get although is perpendicular but it doesn't pass through p3 .**
[image: wrong result]

Comment: `var p3 = Offset.lerp(p1, p2, 0.5); var v = p2 - p1; var p4 = p3 + Offset(v.dy, -v.dx);` - now you have two offsets: `p3` and `p4` for your line

Comment: @pskink is this rotating on its middle origin? because the point could be anywhere along the line

Comment: `p3` is in between `p1` and `p2`, basically `Offset.lerp(p1, p2, 0.5);` is the same as `(p1 + p2) / 2`

Comment: @pskink p3 could be anywhere in between p1 and p2. not always midpoint of p1 and p2

Comment: did you check `Offsset.lerp` official documentation?

Comment: and as i see the sources you can use any value as the last parameter - not only in range [0..1] - indeed the docs say: *"The interpolation can be extrapolated beyond 0.0 and 1.0, so negative values and values greater than 1.0 are valid (and can easily be generated by curves such as Curves.elasticInOut)."*

Comment: Yes , I got it! the second part is using dot product?

Comment: yes, dot product: `a1*b1 + a2*b2 = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've just over-complicated your algebra a little.

The slope `m` of the `p1-p2` line is given by:

```
m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Then the equation of the line perpendicular to `p1-p2` passing through `p3` is:

```
(y-y3)/(x-x3) = -1/m
```

Rearranging gives:

```
x = (y3-y)*m + x3
```

Therefore:

```
double findX1 = (p3.y-qy1)*m + p3.x;
double findX2 = (p3.y-qy2)*m + p3.x;
```

where `qy1 = 0, qy2 = screenHeight`, as in your code.

What happens when `p3` is such that `findX1` and/or `findX2` are less than zero or greater than `screenWidth`? Do you then want to snap the line to the left or right?